# Print All Possible Combinations with Conditions?

Tags: php, function, combinations

I have these variables:

```
$letters = array('a','b','c','1','2','3', .....);
$min_length = any number ;
$max_length = any number;
$must_include = array('letter1','letter2', .....); // list of letters and numbers that must be in combination
$must_exclude = array('letter3','letter3', .....); // list of letters and numbers that must not be in combination
```

I need a function to print all possible combinations depending on the given variables.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score -1):

This isolated problem can be solved using php's `array_*` functions.

1. First, let's define the variables:

   ```
   $letters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
   $min_length = 5;
   $max_length = 15;
   $must_include = array('a','e', 't', '7');
   $must_exclude = array('4','q', 'j', '9');
   ```
2. For simpler solution, let's define a fixed length of result as variable, based on the `$min_length` and `$max_length` value:

   ```
   $actual_length = rand($min_length, $max_length);
   ```
3. Next step, let's prepare the clean letters by removing `and` from it:

   ```
   $clean_letters = array_diff($letters, $must_exclude);
   $clean_letters = array_diff($letters, $must_include);
   ```

   > Please note that the reason why I removed the `$must_include` and `$must_exclude` is, because, later below, I'll include `$must_include` in result since it MUST be included.
4. Now, for the actual result:

   ```
   $result = $must_include;
   $result = array_merge($result, array_rand($letters, $actual_length - sizeof($result)));
   ```

   > in this step, I default the `$result` to be `$must_include` and then, merged it with random value from `$letters` to the size of `$actual_length`'s size minus `$must_include`'s size.

All of the steps above will result in values that's always have letters in `$must_include` and omit `$must_exclude`'s letters.

Full script below:

```
<?php

$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
$min_length = 5;
$max_length = 15;
$must_include = array('a','e', 't', '7');
$must_exclude = array('4','q', 'j', '9');

$actual_length = rand($min_length, $max_length);

echo "Length: " . $actual_length . ".\n";


if( count(array_intersect($must_include, $must_exclude)) > 0 ){
    die("Value in $must_include MUST NOT present in $must_exclude.\n");
}

if( count(array_intersect($must_exclude, $must_include)) > 0 ){
    die("Value in $must_exclude MUST NOT present in $must_include.\n");
}

if(sizeof($must_include) > $min_length){
    die("\$min_length MUST BE larger or equal to \$must_include.\n");
}

if(!$actual_length <= $max_length || $actual_length >= $min_length){
} else {
    die("\$actual_length MUST BE between \$min_length to \$max_length.\n");
}

$clean_letters = array_diff($letters, $must_exclude);
$clean_letters = array_diff($letters, $must_include);

// echo implode(", ", $clean_letters) . "\n";

$result = $must_include;
$result = array_merge($result, array_rand($letters, $actual_length - sizeof($result)));


echo "Must Include: " . implode(", ", $must_include) . "\n";
echo "Must Exclude: " . implode(", ", $must_exclude) . "\n";
echo "Result (" . sizeof($result) . "): " . implode(", ", $result) . "\n";
```